# Embed text from other sheets inside QUERY()

Tags: google-sheets

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE(Data),"SELECT Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4")
```

I have a simple formula of the format above. The data inside importrange() is in another Google Sheets file.

However, within this particular file I have the QUERY() formula in, I would like to refer to cells in another sheet and use these to create columns inside query.

Before the Col1 inside QUERY() above, I need two separate columns:

PO, Supplier

Where PO is (in normal formula format): "PO-"&Control!A6&"-"&Control!A5 (this is basically text string "PO-" combined with Control cell A6, text string "-" and Control cell A5)

and supplier is simply Control!A6.

How can I amend these two so they are columns within QUERY()?

Answer (score 1):

example could be:

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE(Data),
 "select Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4
  where Col1 = 'PO-"&Control!A6&"-"&Control!A5&"'
    and Col2 = '"&Control!A6&"'", )
```

Comment: Amending the function I wrote above to your suggested solution gives blanks (except the headers). Here is a view only version to check:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mKQWXHQdoTJYil4548OD93Dg3ynP5RVz7dYSD9K6wkI/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: `=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE(Control!$B$4,"Main!A:Z"),"select 'PO-"&Control!B6&"-"&Control!B5&"','"&Control!B5&"',Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4 where Col3 IS NOT NULL label 'PO-"&Control!B6&"-"&Control!B5&"' 'Order Ref', '"&Control!B5&"' 'Company', Col1 'Item Code',Col2 'Item Name', Col3 'Item Price', Col4 'Item Qty'")`

Made it work via the above